# Android ListView not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android, listview

I have struggled to load more items on listview after calling notifyDataSetChanged() method
Here is the code block for setting user scroll action on listview

```
lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(), getList(), 2);
progressDialog.show();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                userScrolled = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (userScrolled) {
                userScrolled = false;
                progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                progressDialog.show();
                updateListView();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is my updateListView method:

```
private void updateListView() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (appPreference.getLoadStatus().equals("0")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < getListMore().size(); i++) {
                    Log.i("MORE VALUES", "" + getListMore().get(i));
                    getList().add(getListMore().get(i));
                }
                appPreference.saveLoadStatus("1");
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Here is my `getList()` method

```
public List<ItemList> getList() {
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    String where = Products.SYNCSTATUS + " != 3";
    Cursor c = cr.query(Products.BASEURI, null, where, null, Products.ID + " DESC");
    list = new ArrayList<ItemList>();
    try {
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                int colN = c.getColumnIndex(Products.PRODUCT);
                int colP = c.getColumnIndex(Products.ON_HAND);
                int colI = c.getColumnIndex(Products.ID);
                int colD = c.getColumnIndex(Products.SKU);
                int colPr = c.getColumnIndex(Products.PRICE);
                int colUp = c.getColumnIndex(Products.UPDATE);
                String n = c.getString(colNad);
                String p = c.getString(colPle);
                long i = c.getLong(colIMEI);
                String d = c.getString(colDec);
                String pr = c.getString(colProd);
                String upd = c.getString(colUpdated);
                if (!Validating.areSet(upd))
                    upd = getString(R.string.strnever);
                if (tabletsize) {
                    list.add(new ItemList(n.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()), pr, p, i,
                            d, upd));
                } else {
                    list.add(new ItemList(getString(R.string.strproduct).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " +
                            n.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            getString(R.string.strprice).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " +
                                    pr.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            getString(R.string.strtotalqty).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " + p, i,
                            getString(R.string.strsku).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " + d,
                            getString(R.string.strlastsell).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " + upd));
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else {
            String n = getString(R.string.strnodata).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
            String p = " ";
            long i = 0;
            String d = null;
            list.add(new ItemList(n, "", p, i, d));
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

My intention is to load more items using `getListMore()` method which load data from database, add them into `getList()` method which returns `List<ItemList>` 
The problem comes when i scroll the listview there is no new data loaded onto it ,the logs shows the 
`Log.i("MORE VALUES", "" + getListMore().get(i));` returned the data from database but no data has been shown on listview.
Can anyone help with the issue as why the data is not loaded and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: The line `getList().add(getListMore().get(i));` looks suspicious, can you post the implementation of `getList()`?

Comment: show me your getList() method

Comment: I have posted the getList() method ,please look at it

Answer (score 0):

You are actually fetching the data, adding it into list with `getList()` but not setting that list. you probably need to `setlist()` with new values. 
Something like, `setList(new updated list here)` and then `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

you need to make `getList()` more clear, see every time you get `getList()` and add new item in it, it reinstanitate the list, add the old items in it which you have added veru first time. better to make a change the method something like this.

```
    public List<ItemList> getList() {
    if(list != null || list.size() > 0) {
      return list;
    }
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        String where = Products.SYNCSTATUS + " != 3";
        Cursor c = cr.query(Products.BASEURI, null, where, null, Products.ID + " DESC");
  list = new ArrayList<ItemList>();
                try {
            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    int colN = c.getColumnIndex(Products.PRODUCT);
                    int colP = c.getColumnIndex(Products.ON_HAND);
                    int colI = c.getColumnIndex(Products.ID);
                    int colD = c.getColumnIndex(Products.SKU);
                    int colPr = c.getColumnIndex(Products.PRICE);
                    int colUp = c.getColumnIndex(Products.UPDATE);
                    String n = c.getString(colNad);
                    String p = c.getString(colPle);
                    long i = c.getLong(colIMEI);
                    String d = c.getString(colDec);
                    String pr = c.getString(colProd);
                    String upd = c.getString(colUpdated);
                    if (!Validating.areSet(upd))
                        upd = getString(R.string.strnever);
                    if (tabletsize) {
                        list.add(new ItemList(n.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()), pr, p, i,
                                d, upd));
                    } else {
                        list.add(new ItemList(getString(R.string.strproduct).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " +
                                n.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                                getString(R.string.strprice).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " +
                                        pr.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                                getString(R.string.strtotalqty).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " + p, i,
                                getString(R.string.strsku).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " + d,
                                getString(R.string.strlastsell).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + ": " + upd));
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } else {
                String n = getString(R.string.strnodata).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
                String p = " ";
                long i = 0;
                String d = null;
                list.add(new ItemList(n, "", p, i, d));
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Junaid can you explain more ,because dont you think that i have already set the data here **adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(), getList(), 2);** as on my code block?

Comment: Actually **getList()** method returns **List<ItemList>** which i have passed it into adapter **adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(), getList(), 2);**

Comment: can you please post you getters and setters for list?

Comment: I have posted an edit ,i have added the getList() method

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
```

to:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
```

The method `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` needs to be called from the main thread only.

Comment: I have tried but still the same thing ,any other suggestion?